# Why does my windows batch file keep looping after the condition is met?

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

Basically, I want to copy the latest version of an MSI from a server to my local machine. I am trying to loop through a file and grab the first line which holds the latest version of the MSI to grab. I am not entirely familiar with the weirdness of for loops and if statements in batch files. Here is the code I have that keeps looping after it finds the first line:

```
cd %~dp0

mkdir "c:\MyApp\QA\msi"

rem Determine what folder is the latest version of QA
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
dir /b /o-n "\\my-server\folder\another_folder\5.0.*" > output.txt
SET /a counter=1
SET version=""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (output.txt) do (
if "counter"==1 goto install (
xcopy "\\my-server\folder\another_folder\%%a\myinstaller.msi" "c:\MyApp\QA\msi\myinstaller.msi" /y
)
SET /a counter+=1
)

goto exit

:exit

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
if "counter"==1 goto install (
```

`"counter"` can *never* be equal to `1`. On the other hand, **`!counter!`** might.

Explanation (in case you need it):

`"counter"` is a literal, a word *counter* in double quotes. You are comparing it to another literal, `1`. Obviously the two don't match. What is most probably meant in that part of the script is evaluating the *variable* `counter` and comparing the value with `1`. In bracketed command blocks one typically uses delayed expansion, hence `!counter!` (as opposed to `%counter%`).

On a different note, the said line seems somewhat unusual. It contains the `goto` command and another command *after* it. I don't think that the command that follows `goto` is likely to be executed. Possibly `goto install` is redundant.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was definitely doing that stuff wrong. I got it working now ... much appreciated.